# codeigniter session destroy after redirect to another controller in codeigniter version 3.1.9

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CI version 3.1.9. After login i set session like `

```
$arr = array('user_name'=>$result['data']['user_name']);
$this->session->set_userdata('adminsessiondetails',$arr);
echo "<pre> ";print_r($this->session->userdata('adminsessiondetails'));`
```

showing session details but after redirect to dashboard controller and there    i print session. It shows blank array.

```
if(!($this->session->userdata('adminsessiondetails'))) {
    redirect('LoginController'); 
}
```

I have loaded session in autoload.php

how t fix it?

Comment: can we check your dashboard codes ?

Comment: i solved it. i notice that session library in codeigniter is not autoloading itself . so i manualy load library in dashboard controller's contructor and then it is working fine.